# Understanding the logic behing a menu with active elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a css rule like this:

```
.foo:active {
    background-position: 0px -382px;
}
```

.foo is applied to an anchor.

I have a set of several buttons displayed side by side.

I need to have a very common behaviour here:

When the user clicks on button 1, it stays active.
If the user clicks on button 2, that should be active and the orders shouldn't.
If we click on button 3 the same thing... and so on...
So, we should only allow one active button.

Can we deal with this using javascript or should we rely on a server side language?

Perhaps javascript will do the job, since, here, we are not refreshing the page each time the user clicks on one of those buttons.

What is the logic behind this ?

**Update:**
I should add something to onclick event, I should allow to onclick, apply a class that places the background in a way that the element looks active. But, I'm not sure, how to deal with the part that ONLY ONE of those 9 should be active. :s

**Note:** should I provide more details, please, let me know.

---

**CODE SAMPLE:**

```
function showDetails(eid){
  $.post(baseUrl+"/index/show.details",{id:eid},function(e){

  ...

  //remove ativoFinalista class from all elements with .botoesEquipas class.
  $('.botoesEquipas').removeClass('ativoFinalista'); 

  //add the class to the clicked element
  $(this).addClass('ativoFinalista'); 

 }, 'json');
}
```

**Css:**

I have nothing defined for .botoesEquipas.

```
.ativoFinalista {
    background-position: 0px -130px;
}
```

**The anchor:**

```
<a class="botoesEquipas botaoFinalista<?php echo $e["cod_team"];?>"
 href="javascript:;" onclick="showDetails(<?php echo $e["cod_team"];?>)"><?php echo$e["name"];?></a>
```

Comment: I take the view that jQuery would be extremely useful here.

Comment: @pimvdb: Can you provide a quick example of something so that I could grab the logic behind please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery, but note that a *class* `fooactive` is needed:

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
    $('.foo').removeClass('fooactive'); // Remove active class from all elements of class foo
    $(this).addClass('fooactive');      // Add active class to this specific one
});
```

Then code CSS like:

```
.foo { /* default foo style */ }
.fooactive { /* extra styles when active */ }
```

**Edit:** You bind click functions the old way. In that case, pass the element like:

```
onclick="showDetails(123,this)"
```

and

```
function showDetails(eid, element){
  $('.foo').removeClass('fooactive'); 
  $(element).addClass('fooactive'); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eEJma/

Comment: @pimvdg: $(this).addClass('fooactive'); isn't working. He removes the class on all .foo, but it doesn't add the fooactive class on the element I click on. :(

Comment: @pimvdg - I've added some code to my question. Could it be the fact that I'm using onClick() inside html, instead of call a function... ? I mean, perhaps, this, is something else on my code ?

Comment: @MEM: That's because you've moved it to another function, where `this` has another value. Use `$('some selector to select the element to become active').addClass('fooactive')`.

Comment: Here is a comment to say "This is correct. I have tried it and it works" and not to say anything more or less.

Comment: @pimvdb: (please be patient) :( I don't understand what this: "some selector to select the element to become active" could be. I mean, the selector to select the element to become active will be .fooactive , no ?

Comment: @pimvdb: perhaps something like this? $('.botaoFinalista'+e) ? I will give it a try...

Comment: @pimvdb: please leave your post with the old case as well. Your update did the trick. 

Now I have a very weird behaviour because, it changes on click, but since I have a CSS class applied on hover, we will see the onlick event effect, only, when we roll out! :(( I should perhaps disable the css :hover somehow ? - I will add another question with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would use jQuery. There is no need to call back to a server-side language:

Logic:

1. Remove all `active` classes
2. Add `active` to the clicked button.